# Is there any frameworks for integration testing of Android apps which can drive emulator/device beyond one app

Tags: android, testing

I found couple of difference frameworks which can test Android apps, but all of them are limited on testing of just one app (because mainly they use Instrumentation)

My app contains a service which could be called by other apps and I want to automate testing of this too. So, I would like to be able to write some tests which automate UI in other apps.

Have you seen anything, except MonkeyRunner? I looked at it, but the API is quite poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Sikuli IDE](http://sikuli.org/) it's easy enough to use and is based on Python.

You can bascially run integration tests using it, (kind of like Selenium for desktops).

There is also [Selenium Android Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver) if you want to run automaton tests from the Android WebView!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a bare monkeyrunner is perhaps not enough, but if you combine it with other tools perhaps you can find your way. For example, [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) is a library that adds the ability of:

- finding Views by ID, very much like you normally do in your Android Activity (using `ViewClient.findViewById()`)
- obtaining the value for almost any of the Views properties (using for example `View.isChecked()` or `View.mText()`)
- sending touch events to the Views by simply invoking `View.touch()`

More details an a complete example can be found at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html